# How to get the equation numbering paretheses right with arabic?

Tags: numbering, arabic

```
\documentclass[fontsize=15pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}% without it I get the (0.1) (0.2)


\newtcolorbox{myremark}[1]{%
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-2mm},
    coltitle=black,colbacktitle=red!45!white,enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#1,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=yellow!80,
 }


 \begin{document}
     hello \textarabic{السلام عليكم} how are you
     \begin{myremark}{\textarabic{ملاحظة}}
          \begin{Arabic}
مثال على الرياضيات باللغة العربية
        \end{Arabic}
        \begin{equation}
            \frac{d}{dx}(\sin x) = \cos x
        \end{equation}
    \end{myremark}

    \begin{myremark}{\textarabic{ملاحظة}}
\begin{Arabic}
    مثال على الرياضيات باللغة العربية
\end{Arabic}
    \begin{equation}
             \frac{d}{dx}(\sin x) = \cos x
    \end{equation}
\end{myremark}

\end{document}

I get the parentheses like this )1( and )2(
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: `left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=1cm`.

Comment: Instead of `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}`, try `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=15pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\newtcolorbox{myremark}[1]{%
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-2mm},
    coltitle=black,colbacktitle=red!45!white,enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#1,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=yellow!80,
}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}} % Revert to default Arabic numbering style for equations

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\normalfont\upshape(#1)}} % Ensure equation numbers are always upright
\makeatother

\begin{document}

hello \textarabic{السلام عليكم} how are you
\begin{myremark}{\textarabic{ملاحظة}}
    \begin{Arabic}
        مثال على الرياضيات باللغة العربية
    \end{Arabic}
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{d}{dx}(\sin x) = \cos x
    \end{equation}
\end{myremark}

\begin{myremark}{\textarabic{ملاحظة}}
    \begin{Arabic}
        مثال على الرياضيات باللغة العربية
    \end{Arabic}
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{d}{dx}(\sin x) = \cos x
    \end{equation}
\end{myremark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works, thanks, but I don't understand it at all,

Comment: @NeoMosaid I have put the comments with `%`.

Comment: yes thank you. I looked into it to understand the code, is some advanced stuff for me :D. changing the internal  command ``\tagform@`` .